# Is HTML tag make JSON file not valid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

Hey, I have a little problem here. 
I can load JSON file using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` with this code

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSError *error = nil;
   NSDictionary *JSONdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        self.data = JSONdata;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}];
```

but the JSONdata became null when I load this JSON from someurl.com/json.html
here is the JSON

```
{
"status": 200,
"results": [
    {
        "author": {
            "username": "user1",
            "full_name": "User 1"
        }
    }
]
}
<!-- This document saved from someurl.com/json.html -->
```

I tried to download that file and access it from loaclhost, and still got null. and then I remove that html tag  `<!-- This document saved from someurl.com/json.html -->` manually, and then the JSON can be load.

My conclusion is, the html tag that make JSON not valid. 
What do I have to do remove that tag from JSON file? or I have to add some code to NSJSONSerialization?

Answer (score 3):

A JSON string must be completely selfcontained. it cannot contain anything other than the JSON data. Consider it to be pretty much identical to the right-hand-side of a Javascript variable assignment:

```
var x = {"status":200};
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---raw json text
```

If you have anything before **OR** after the json data, you're basically creating a javascript syntax error

```
var x = foo{"status":200}bar;
        ^^^---           ^^^---
```

If your case, the `bar` above would be the HTML comment. Either it's fully valid JSON, or it's completely invalid. There's no in-between.

Comment: oh i see. how to handle this, since i cant do anything with the source JSON? should I download the whole file and separate the json only?

Comment: yes. if you have no control over the json provider, you'll have to massage the "broken" data into valid json. but really... the provider should fix their broken system.

Comment: now i can separate the json from html tag, but it results NSString. how to convert it into nsdictionary?

Comment: Take a look at the NSJSONSerialization Class and JSONObjectWithData

Comment: `NSDictionary *dictFromJson = [NSJSONSerialization 
    JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
    options:kNilOptions 
    error:nil];` will change your string into nsdictionary